# original image resize shows only default placeholder image

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to get this piece of code to work in **magento 1.7.0**...

it only displays the magento placeholder image...

if i change **"image"** to **"small_image"** it works fine

everything is set up in the back end the radio buttons are selected for the product images... I have cleared the cache also...

this is happening in the `list.phtml` file ...

can someone kind enough tell me what i am doing wrong or WHY its not working... i have been searching all over i found one solution after 3 days of searching and it didn't work....

`$_item` is not defined so a i get a call to a non object error...

here's a link to the answere

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995206/get-base-product-image-in-magento

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(171, 259);
```

Comment: Why not set products to use the same image path for `small_image` as they are currently using for `image`?

Answer (score 5):

You are in the template of the product list. Magento collections don't load all the attributes by default, image e.g. is not loaded.

Go to the backend `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > image` and set "Show in product Listing" to "yes"

Comment: When I go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > image I don't see an option to 'Show in product listing'.  The only editable parts are the scope and the 'apply to'. Has this changed in different versions?

Comment: Ok, I've found an answer to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579834

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885942/magento-original-image-resize-only-shows-placeholder-image

Not sure if it's possible to merge two questions in some mode.

Comment: yea i got an answer on stackoverflow i am going to delete this one or we should leave it as is... just in case there is a link going to the other answer anyways...

Comment: $product->load IS WRONG. DON'T DO IT!

Comment: Explanation - sorry to not writing it down with the complainment. Magento uses EAV to save all the attributes in one table (more or less - details...) and if you want to load a product you have to join a few times into this table. To avoid too much joins magento collections only load the attributes you need. You can "easily" change this and add attributes. Using load() in a foreach means: loading 30 products with 1 query and then shoot 1 query per product to the db -> really bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the GD library is loaded in your php.ini:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

If it's not loaded, Magento will just silently not resize the image and return the default placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that that **developer mode** is set to **false** 
this can be done from the root **.htaccess file** by setting this to the end of the file:

`SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"`

and what this will do is set:

`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` to `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);` in the index.php file