# After resizing original image showing placeholder image in My account page

Tags: magento-1.9

we are trying below code to display product thumbinal image in My account section, its working fine.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
$imageUrl=  Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" />
```

but when we tried to Resize image with help of below code, its displaying **Placeholder image**

```
$imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(150 ,150)->setQuality(100);
```

i followed [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2873/original-image-resize-shows-only-default-placeholder-image) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885942/magento-original-image-resize-only-shows-placeholder-image) , both didt worked for me.

**edit**

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br>';
     echo $product->getId().'<br />';



    $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150 ,150)->setQuality(100);


    ?>  

<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" />



<form action="<?php echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>" method="post">  
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" >
    <span><span>
    <?php echo $buttonTitle ?>
    </span></span>
</button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

</div>
</form>
<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100%;'>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: I think you are using wrong variable. try with `$_product` in place of `$product` in your code

Comment: @JaiminSutariya now its giving `Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php` in line `$this->_getModel()->setBaseFile($this->getProduct()->getData($this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()));`

Comment: It will require full code of your file to debug the issue. Please update question with the same.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya please check updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code in your phtml.

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br>';
     echo $product->getId().'<br />';

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

    $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150 ,150)->setQuality(100);


    ?>  

<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" />



<form action="<?php echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>" method="post">  
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" >
    <span><span>
    <?php echo $buttonTitle ?>
    </span></span>
</button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

</div>
</form>
<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100%;'>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: dont know what to say for your support, thanks will be very less..... worked fine....

Answer (score 0):

the creation of a new project generate an hard load.

This is a better solution, using load('media_gallery'):

```
...

 echo $product->getName().' <br>';
 echo $product->getId().'<br />';

$_product->load('media_gallery');

$imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150 ,150)->setQuality(100);


?>  
...
```